# OnCheckChanged not Firing when Unchecked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I've googled this topic as much as i could, ive found similar topics around and even on stackoverflow but none were able to resolve my issue. I have a nested gridview bound to a sqldatasource that populates a few fields as well as a checkbox field from a 'bits' field in the database. The checkboxes populate correctly from the database (checked vs. unchecked) but my 'OnCheckedChanged' event only fires when i check a checkbox but does NOT fire when it is unchecked, the page just goes through its post back. I have 'EnableViewState' set to true on the master page, local page, and on the control as well as auto post back. What i need to do is update the DB with the new value of the checkbox (checked vs unchecked) and reload. Please let me know if anyone has suggestions.

```
Protected Sub Gridview3_OnCheckedChanged(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim checkbox As CheckBox = TryCast(Sender, CheckBox)
    Dim gridview3 As GridView = checkbox.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
    Dim row As GridViewRow = checkbox.Parent.Parent
    sql_insert(String.Format("UPDATE [STOREIT2-PORTAL].dbo.AA5VOLUMES SET PROTECTED = '{0}' WHERE GUID = '{1}' AND AGENTID = '{2}'", checkbox.Checked, gridview3.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values("GUID").ToString, gridview3.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values("AgentID").ToString))
End Sub

<asp:GridView ID="Gridview3" EnableViewState="true" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AgentID,GUID" OnRowDataBound="GridView3_OnRowDataBound" RowStyle-CssClass ="row" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="altrow" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="gvmain"> <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow"></AlternatingRowStyle>
       <columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="AgentID" HeaderText="AgentID" SortExpression="AgentID" visible="false"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="GUID" HeaderText="GUID" SortExpression="GUID" visible="false"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="VolumeName" HeaderText="VolumeName" SortExpression="VolumeName" readonly="true"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Label" HeaderText="Label" SortExpression="Label" nulldisplaytext="<i>{No Label}</i>" readonly="true"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="BaseCount" HeaderText="BaseCount" SortExpression="BaseCount" nulldisplaytext="<i>{No Base Images}</i>" readonly="true"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeStamp" HeaderText="TimeStamp" SortExpression="TimeStamp" nulldisplaytext="<i>{Volume has no recent snapshots}</i>" readonly="true"/>
           <asp:TemplateField headertext="Protected">
              <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="Protected" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" autopostback="true" checked='<%# Eval("Protected")%>' OnCheckedChanged="Gridview3_OnCheckedChanged"/>  
              </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
       </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing your code does not have the 'Handles Clause' Maybe this is causing the problem you mention. . .

```
Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
```

Comment: i think the issue is when the page does its postback the sqldatasource is recreating the checkbox and assigning it the original value. I can seem to get around grabbing that value and updating the SQL DB before the page posts and i lose it.